# Android Application fails while running in device without debugger attached

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intentservice

I have an android app engine connected application in eclipse. All the datastore operations are performed in background using Asynctask and intentservice. My application works perfectly fine while debugging in eclipse. But when I detach from debugger and run the application in my device, the application fails and I get message of Application Not Responding on button clicks.The android version in my device is 2.3.6.

What may be the possible reasons? I am not sure but I doubt some database concurrency issues may also be the reason.

Comment: Show us the logcat output

Comment: @greg-449 Is there someway I can get the logcat output when my device in not connected to computer?

Comment: It was a small mistake of not commenting on the line   android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger(). When i commented on this line , the app is working in device without hanging up.